# Should I ensure characters in user input follow ASCII?

Tags: javascript, php, web, non-ascii-characters

I am writing an online form which I am checking client-side through JavaScript and server-side through PHP though was wondering, should I be validating that the user doesn't include non-ASCII characters?

For instance, is there any way that programming languages would throw errors or give me any problems if I don't handle these characters - or should they be capable of dealing with them?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Depends on the form, doesn't it? Which reason would it have to restrict the charset other than improper encoding handling?

Comment: See also: [How to support UTF-8 completely in a web application](http://stackoverflow.com/q/279170)

Comment: In this case, it is just a registration form - though I was wondering is it possible that someone could use special characters to purposefully crash a system by causing such languages to throw errors when met with unknown characters?

Comment: @harryjamesuk I would worry more about delimiters like `'` or `"`. They can cause more trouble. `a` however should be as harmless as ``.

Comment: @Xufox Thanks for your reply - that's what I was looking for :)

Comment: @Xufox "I would worry more about delimiters like ' or "." --- that is such a harmful statement for a newbie.

Comment: @harryjamesuk what they suggested in general is harmful. There is nothing wrong in quote characters. You should worry about how you use **any** data, not any particular characters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't limit your users to ASCII unless there is a good reason to do so. UTF-8 encoded Unicode is supported by almost everything, so stick with that unless there's a good reason not to.

If you're not familiar with character encoding, I'd recommend this article: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html